# why I click the script in Element does not turn to the Source panel in develop tools on chrome beta 40

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, frontend, developer-tools

i found a strange problem,when i click the script link ,it does not redrect to source panel in develop tools,[image]

I find it work well in chrome 39 stable,how strange,it bring some trouble to view the source code,i had to find it on source panel,dose any body meet the problem the same with me??

Answer (score 0):

This is because thats a developer tool`s editor and allows you to edit or customize on the go, so that you can make changes and it can be reflected at the run time. So, for the links in the editor must be copied and then gave to be pasted in the URL Bar.